# Integrability of the composition of continuous with Riemann integrable counter example?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

When I talk about integrability, I mean Riemann integrability. I also mean both their domains are [a,b].

If $f$ is integrable, and $g$ is continuous, then $g \circ f$ is a integrable function.
I strongly suspect that $f \circ g $ will not necessarily be integrable.  Could anyone give me a counterexample?

Comment: When you say "integrable", you mean on every closed, bounded interval, right? We're not talking about convergence of improper integrals, right?

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much. I mean the domain is compact indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample showing that $f \circ g$ under these hypotheses need not be Riemann integrable.

Take $f$ as the Riemann integrable function defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x=0 \\ 1, &x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

It is possible to construct a continuous function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $F \subset [0,1]$ (nowhere dense with positive measure),we have  $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in F$ and $g(x) > 0$ for $x \in [0,1] \setminus F$.

In this case, $f \circ g$ is discontinuous on $F$ and, hence, not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

To show that $f \circ g$ is discontinuous on $F$, note that $F$ has empty interior. For each point $x \in F$ we have $f(g(x))=0$, but for  **any** interval $I_\delta = (x- \delta,x+\delta)$ there are points $y \in I_\delta \cap F^c$ where $f(g(y)) = 1$.